# C++ dilemma: About std::stoi

Tags: c++, string, int, type-conversion

I have a dilemma, which boils down to (The specific case is more involved):

1. Concatenate numeric chars `nc` and apply `std::stoi` in the end.
2. Initialize `int x=0;`. In each iteration: `x *= 10; x += (nc & 0xCF);`

What would be more efficient, given the number of digits will normally always be less than ,say, 6?

Comment: You're just gonna have to measure it to know for sure. Since the number of characters is so small, I would even test a `switch-case` construct that uses fall through to handle different number of characters.

Comment: @Praetorian I wonder what `stoi` is *actually* doing..

Comment: I don't think the standard places any restrictions on what it can do, as far as conversion goes. I have looked at the VS2013 implementation, and IIRC, they call `strtol`, and add error checking after that.

Comment: @Praetorian, From what I recall, the standard either makes it use `strtol`, or very strongly encourages it to. It describes error handling in terms of `strtol` results.

Comment: @Praetorian really..? I think that answers my question

Comment: @chris You're right, [string.conversions] says both `stoi` and `stol` call `strtol`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 2 is almost certainly more efficient.  It uses constant memory, avoids dynamic allocation, and does less work than `std::stoi` (which handles alternate bases, and therefore is unlikely to optimize the multiplication step)

Maintainability is also a consideration.  Programmers willing to use their brain should be able to understand #2, especially with an accompanying comment.  Unfortunately my experience is that if you have any cargo cult programmers working on your codebase, they'll probably have a strong preference for #1.

I'm not sure about that magic number `0xCF`, however.  Don't you just want `x += nc - '0';` ?  It's portable and, being idiomatic, easier to understand.  Masking with `0xCF` on the other hand assumes ASCII.  Neither one does anything sensible with characters outside the `'0' <= nc && nc <='9'` range, but if I were using bitwise arithmetic, I'd mask with `0x0F`.

Comment: I always go for bit-wise when possible, for many many reasons